# JUnit spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, junit

I am writing JUnit test cases for my Spring Boot Application in which dynamically data is generated through various APIs. I wanted to truncate all the test data after test cases are passed. But is it advisable to write a test case which will truncate the data at the end of Unit testing. But provided that the developed application does not have a delete API and the API is solely developed only for JUnit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good practice is to create a database during your build process or within your test which will be automatically dropped afterwards. Some people use [H2 database](http://h2database.com/html/main.html) for testing.

Comment: Thank you sir it really helps me a lot.  And also it is working fine for me